# UI5 UploadCollection Issue

Tags: upload, sapui5

I have an UploadCollection in my XML view bound to a JSONModel. When I add / delete files in the collection all works good initially. When I save the required data to the database and then refresh the JSONModel from the database I get the attached error. It is as if the elements are not being removed from the DOM, however, when I look at the entire process via the Chrome debgugger the elements are indeed gone in between. I am currently using OpenUI5 v1.78.1 but the same issue occurs with the latest (v1.86.3). The UploadCollection fails to work again from then on and I need to destroy it in my view before the data will be displayed again.

Has anyone seen this or have advice on how it may be corrected?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It appears that when I was calling `UploadCollection.removeItem(item);` it did not unregister the element somewhere and held onto the idea that the HTML elements still existed. Using `item.destroy();` instead solved the issue.